# Создание объекта при помощи рефлексии

Tags: c#

Хочу узнать, как с помощью рефлексии создать объект класса, у которого явно прописан конструктор. Предположим есть класс Student:

```
class Student
{
    private int _temp = 10;
    private string name = "Vasya";

}
```

В таком случае использование рефлексии при создании экземпляра выглядит следующим образом:

```
class Program
{  
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type type = typeof(Student);

        ConstructorInfo info = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
        object student = info.Invoke(new object[] { });
     }
}
```

Но если в моем студенте появится явно прописанный конструктор, например такой:

```
class Student
{
    private int temp;
    private string name;

    public Student(int temp, string name)
    {
        this.temp = temp;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

то как именно я должен передать параметры в вызывающей части программы? А именно тут:

```
 ConstructorInfo info = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
 object student = info.Invoke(new object[] { });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нужно получить такой конструктор:

```
ConstructorInfo info = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(string) });
```

И передать в него параметры:

```
object student = info.Invoke(new object[] { 20, "Petya" });
```

Answer (score 5):

Почему бы не просто

```
var student = (Student)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Student), 1, "Vasya");
```